# Для чего нужен интерфейс icomparable? - простыми словами

Tags: c#

Для чего нужен интерфейс icomparable? Я новичок и прошу объяснить на пальцах зачем он нужен и что он делает?

Comment: он позволяет сравнивать объекты

Comment: Если класс его реализует то можно применять операции < > <= == и все такое

Comment: @VladimirPaliukhovich, не, у него можно вызвать [`CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx) - а операторы - тут могут быть не связаны никак

Comment: @Grundy: Могут, да. Но хорошие девочки и мальчики определяют `CompareTo` и сравнение через `>` согласованным образом.

Comment: @VladD, да :) но операторы вообще не обязательно определять

Answer (score 10, accepted):

tl;dr: Интерфейс `IComparable` нужен потому, что иначе нельзя использовать сравнение в функциях, которые работают с произвольным типом данных.

---

Смотрите.

Для того, чтобы упорядочить объекты, их нужно сравнивать. Если тип объектов известен заранее, то для сравнения проще всего использовать операторы `>`/`=`.

Теперь вопрос, а как же сравнивать объекты, если тип их неизвестен? Например, если у нас есть набор элементов произвольного типа (например, generic-типа `T`)? Для того, чтобы выразить идею «объект X что-то умеет», в .NET используются *интерфейсы*.

Но в интерфейсе нельзя выразить «объект умеет сравниваться с другим». Поэтому и был придуман интерфейс `IComparable` (а также его более современный собрат `IComparable<T>`), который описывает операцию сравнения.

Пример: пускай вы хотите написать функцию `Max`, которая находит максимальный элемент из списка.

Простой пример — `Max` для чисел типа `int`. Как мы помним, для конкретных типов интерфейс не так уж и нужен. Пишем реализацию:

```
int Max(IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    int max = 0;
    bool first = true;
    foreach (var x in list)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
            max = x;
        }
        else
        {
            if (x > max)
                max = x;
        }
    }
    if (first)
        throw new ArgumentException("список пустой!");
    return max;
}
```

Это было несложно. Теперь попробуем обобщить этот метод на произвольный тип `T`. Попробуем обобщить предыдущий метод:

```
T Max<Т>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    T max = default(T);
    bool first = true;
    foreach (var x in list)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
            max = x;
        }
        else
        {
            if (x > max)
                max = x;
        }
    }
    if (first)
        throw new ArgumentException("список пустой!");
    return max;
}
```

Получаем ошибку: `error CS0019: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'`. Потому что компилятор не знает, как ему сравнивать произвольный тип `T` (и можно ли вообще). Вспоминаем про интерфейс `IComparable<T>`, и пользуемся им.

Во-первых, мы потребуем, чтобы объекты типа `T` можно было сравнивать с другими объектами того же типа:

```
T Max<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : IComparable<T>
```

Далее, вместо сравнения через `>` применяем сравнение через `IComparable<T>`:

```
if (x.CompareTo(max) > 0)
    max = x;
```

Пробуем:

```
int[] list = { 1, 7, 2, 99, -14 };
Console.WriteLine(Max(list));
```

— получаем на выходе 99.

---

Заметьте, что если вы определите `operator >` и `operator ==`, то этим самым автоматически не будет поддерживаться интерфейс `IComparable<T>`. Вы должны будете определить его вручную. Можно считать это недостатком в текущей реализации языка.

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Eric Lippert: Double Your Dispatch, Double Your Fun](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun/).

Comment: _чтобы тип T можно было сравнивать с другими_ - тут  скорее: _чтобы **объекты** типа Т можно было сравнивать с другими **объектами** типаТ_

Comment: @Grundy: Угу, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Кстати, а можно накладывать ограничение на generic, чтобы операторы использовать можно было? типа не `a.CompareTo(b)>0`, а просто `a>b`? Вроде нельзя, но может быть определения операторов в интерфейс можно вынести? или уже есть такой стандартный какой-нибудь?

Comment: @Grundy: Не, нельзя. На текущий момент generic-ограничений на статические бинарные операторы нет. (Это понятно, они ж статические!)

Comment: А операторы вообще только статические?

Comment: Добавлю, что желательно, чтобы CompareTo удовлетворяло условиям [отношения частичного порядка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE#.D0.9E.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B). В C# не сталкивался, но в Java как-то получил эксепшен из-за того, что compareTo был не транзитивным.

Comment: @kmv, желательно - это не обязательно :)

Comment: @kmv: Ага, например, при попытке сортировки :)

Comment: @VladD, а не знаете почему пошли по пути IComparable, а не как в C++ с предикатами, в качестве доп. аргументов?

Comment: @ixSci: Думаю, потому, что нету возможности выразить generic constraint «существует статический оператор `static Т::operator > (T, T)`». Генерик-констрейнты бывают на текущий момент лишь (1) имплементирует данный интерфейс, (2) наследуется от данного класса, (3) содержит конструктор без параметров. А то, что невозможно выразить как генерик-констрейнт, нельзя использовать в генерик-методах.

Comment: А если `Func<T, T, bool>` вторым параметром и его вызывать? В С++, в целом, тоже ведь не требуется наличии оператора >, можно любой предикат передать.

Comment: @ixSci: Тогда, конечно, можно. Для этого даже есть [пeрегрузка `List.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @ixSci: И [интерфейс `IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @ixSci: А статических методов в генерик-констрейнтах (как и в интерфейсах), как я понимаю, нет потому, что их невозможно эффективно выразить в объектном коде без рефлексии.